# Convergence/divergence of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{i=0}^k\left(\frac{(-1)^i}{\sqrt{i+1}}\frac{(-1)^{k-i}}{\sqrt{k-i+1}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the series $C:=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{i=0}^k\left(\frac{(-1)^i}{\sqrt{i+1}}\frac{(-1)^{k-i}}{\sqrt{k-i+1}}\right)$ convergent?

I would say no, because:

Let be $c_k:=\sum\limits_{i=0}^k\frac{(-1)^i}{\sqrt{i+1}}\frac{(-1)^{k-i}}{\sqrt{k-i+1}}$, then we get $c_k=\sum\limits_{i=0}^k\frac{(-1)^{k}}{\sqrt{i+1}\sqrt{k-i+1}}=(-1)^k\sum\limits_{i=0}^k\frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}\sqrt{k-i+1}}$. As $(c_k)$ is not a null sequence the limit of the partial sums $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}C_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\sum\limits_{i=0}^k\left(\frac{(-1)^i}{\sqrt{i+1}}\frac{(-1)^{k-i}}{\sqrt{k-i+1}}\right)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^kc_k$ doesn't exist/ $C$ doesn't converge.

Did I miss something?

Comment: @user2661923 I have edited the question.

Comment: What does "null sequence" signify?  Can you demonstrate (for example) that the sequence $\langle c_k\rangle$ does not go to zero?

Comment: You didn't miss to see something mathematically, but you missed to show it ("as (ck) is not a null sequence").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assertion that $(c_k)$ is not a null sequence is correct, and that is the key step in the proof.

Noting that for $0 \leqslant i \leqslant k$ we have $\sqrt{i+1}\sqrt{k-i+1}\leqslant \sqrt{k+1}\sqrt{k-0+1}= k+1$, it follows that

$$|c_k| = \left|(-1)^k\sum_{i=0}^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}\sqrt{k-i+1}}\right|= \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{i+1}\sqrt{k-i+1}}\geqslant \sum_{i=0}^k \frac{1}{k+1}= 1$$

Hence, $\limsup_{k \to \infty} |c_k| \geqslant 1$ and, therefore,  $c_k \not\to 0$ as $k \to \infty$.